# How to restyle a Plotly graph in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, plotly

I have a plotly graph in a custom Angular component:

```html
<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout" (hover)="onHover($event)">
</plotly-plot>
```

I also have a slider, which I want to use to restyle the plot:

```html
<mat-slider
 thumbLabel
 [displayWith]="formatLabel"
 tickInterval="1000"
 min="0"
 max="7000"
 (input)="getSliderVal($event)">
</mat-slider>
```

Currently I am registering the slider change events and redrawing whole graph, which is inefficient. I see there is `(restyle)` prop in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-plotly.js/v/0.1.13) but I don't know how to use it. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I think I have foound a way. In plotly.js [docs](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyreact) it is specified to use `.restyle()` in the folowing way:

```
var update = {
    opacity: 0.4,
    'marker.color': 'red'
};
Plotly.restyle(graphDiv, update, 0);
```

So if you are using Angular you need to specify the plot div ID via `[divId]` like this:

```
<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout" (hover)="onHover($event)" [divId]="embeddingsPlotID">
```

where `embeddingsPlotID` is specified in your component. Then you can call the `.restyle()` like this:

```
PlotlyModule.plotlyjs.restyle("embeddingsPlot",{"marker.size":event.value},0)
```

from your parent component. Sadly in my case this doesen't seem to be much of a speedup compared to redtawing a whole plot (I have cca. 3k points)

Comment: for [divId]="embeddingsPlotID" , it should be added into parent div where the the traces are plotted ?

Comment: One important detail is omitted: component variable this.embeddingsPlotID="embeddingsPlot";